# OnBackKeyPress override method

Tags: windows-phone-7, methods, popup

I want to use the back key to `hide/disable` a pop-up page on Windows phone and I am using the following code to do so.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress( System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )   
{              
   if (myPopupUp.IsOpen)
   {
    myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
    e.Cancel = true;   
   }

   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

But when i run the application it gives an error that saying `"no suitable method found to override"`
Does anyone know the solution for this?
I welcome any ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you overriding the method within a class that extends PhoneApplicationPage?

Comment: I think so..It is a paranoma page that I am working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in my panorama page, I hope you are not overriding this in any of your custom userControl.

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

Comment: @Milan..Thanks, I just realize I was doing so on a UserControl page...I have used the same code I posted on this forum under my panorama page, and it perfectly works fine...thanks for the effort mate..Cheers

Comment: thats what i thought inthe first place ;)
accept/upvote the answer if you feel appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [PhoneApplicationPage.BackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.backkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event instead.

Comment: @Pedro..Obrigadiximo..Ja descobri o que esteve de errado..Um grande Abraco